# Get second element of array after removing elements and updating array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

**Task:** I have `var = array;` in a function that can hold the following sample array - the items represent time (seconds):

`["20.30", "30.55", "8.25", "32.74", "2.75", "39.24"]`

A `setInterval` loop displays the third item (`array[2]`) when a timer exceeds or matches second item in array (`array[1]`). Currently, after that happens, the first two items of array (`array[0]` and `array[1]`) are removed and array variable is re-indexed like so, looping the process until done:

```
array = array.splice(2).filter(function(){return true;});
```

**Dilemma:** I thought it would be easiest to just remove the first two items and update the array this way so as to simply apply a condition like so: `if ( array[1] <= timer ){` but the `splice()` and `filter()` methods - which apply *after* the conditional statement in the loop - don't seem to re-index array variable.

Is there a way to make sure the array variable is re-indexed by new length, or perhaps there is a better way by navigating through the array variable without having to mutate/update it? The latter would perhaps be best, but I am kind of noob in better array manipulation and would appreciate some help.

**UPDATE**

Below I summarize what I clearly wish to attain:

`var array = ["20.30", "30.55", "8.25", "32.74", "2.75", "39.24", etc...]`

Instead of programmatically fetching each and every item iteration (impossible since amount will dynamically change) like follows ...

```
timelinePolling = setInterval(function(e){

...
    
if ( array[1] <= timer ){
    timeline(array[2]); // Apply 3rd item timeline value
    
    } else if ( array[3] <= timer ){
    timeline(array[4]); // Apply 5th item timeline value
}
// etc, for remaining determined/undetermined items.

}, 30);
```

... I wish to iterate and *dynamically* increment the index target of array item variable (what is in brackets) the moment `array[index] <= timer` is achieved, like so (pseudo):

```
timelinePolling = setInterval(function(e){
        
  ...   

  if ( array[end] <= timer ){
  // [end] is always an odd-numbered 0-based indexed item
  // in array list (see Note1 below).
    
  timeline(array[start]);
  // [start] is always an even-numbered 0-based indexed item
  // in array list (see Note2 below).
    
  // Note1: [end] must be swapped with next chronological
  // odd-numbered indexed item in array list at this point in code.
  /* Missing code here! */

  // Note2: [start] must be swapped with next chronological
  // even-numbered indexed item in array list at this point in code.
  /* Missing code here! */

  }

            
}}, 30);
```

So it's the dynamic index increment part that I wish to resolve, which would make my day to say the least. Perhaps my array should be constructed differently to facilitate the task? In this fashion the array must remain intact (no mutation). Any pointers/help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by  " don't seem to re-index array variable."? Also, when you're doing array.splice(2) you are essentially removing all elements starting at your 3rd newly added element (index 2) and returning it to array. Are you looking to achieve this without mutating the original array?

Comment: Make your code runnable here and/or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: It looks like you can use a modification of a circular array to suit your needs. You can use a start marker, end marker in the array without modifying the array.

Comment: @Link - "don't seem to..." is just a hunch for now, since console.log tells me that `array[1]` is undefined on the second loop after splice(2) has been applied. When I am doing splice(2), it removes the first two items, which is the desired result If the array is altered this way, In that case, I guess I need to re-index the remaining items in order for them not to preserve their past index numbers (before removal via splice(2)) in order for array[1] to get the second item that is now there. Mutation is no concern, just as long as array item deletion/shuffling does not break array[1] et al.

Comment: array.splice(2) doesn't remove the first 2 elements, instead it removes all the elements from 2 and returns them, you're storing them back in the array variable overwriting it. Anyway, did you consider using Array.prototype.slice(), it works like splice but does not mutate the original array.

Comment: @user923227 - That sounds like a plan! Start markers and end markers without modifying array would be awesome indeed. If you have any pointers or links to info for such, please share with me. I'll see what I can find/code on my end.

Comment: @Link -  I will try your Array prototype slice() suggestion. In that case it does a copy (clone) of the original? I'll see if it does the job. Thx.

Comment: Array.prototype.slice() will return the removed elements (similar to splice), you need to store them in a new variable, don't overwrite the original 'array'. This way your original array itself will remain untouched.

Comment: @Link : See Update for detailed explanation.

Comment: @user923227 : See Update for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you code in is in the right direction take a look at circular arrays:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/circular-array/

Possibly you are looking at something like this -

```
index = beg;
while (index < end) {
  if( arr[index] < timer) {
    // set beg and end appropriately
    // swap the values you need from the notes 
      // Note1: [end] must be swapped with next chronological
      // odd-numbered indexed item in array list at this point in code.
      /* Missing code here! */

      // Note2: [start] must be swapped with next chronological
      // even-numbered indexed item in array list at this point in code.
      /* Missing code here! */
    timeline(arr[index+1]);
    }
  index += 2; // jump to the next even number.
  index %= arr_len; //check here if there is something that needed to be done for even odd index
}
```

Comment: I haven't been able to adapt your code to sought functionality, but will fiddle again with it some more. In meantime, I got my code working by using global vars for changing them on the fly when dynamically seeking timeline values. This also currently requires a restart via `setInterval` of the parent function spawning that interval. The function is like `timelineNav(endValue, startValue)`, and using global vars so that the `setInterval` code can use them accordingly on the fly. I'll see if something similar can be done with your code. Much thx for input.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with setTimeout, and then you won't have to do the comparison yourself.

At the end of each timeout loop, you splice the array as you suggested, if there are still 3 or more entries in the array then recall the function that sets the timeout.

(The timer here is only to display the total time)
(I reduced your array of number to speed it up)

```js
let timer = 0;
const times = ["4.30", "5.55", "6.25", "6.74", "5.75", "4.24"];

function test(array) {
  const timeInMilliseconds = parseFloat(times[1]) * 1000;
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector('#ignore').innerHTML = array[0];
    document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = array[1];
    document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = array[2];
    
    timer += timeInMilliseconds / 1000;
    document.querySelector('#timer').innerHTML = timer;
    document.querySelector('#array').innerHTML = array;
    array = array.splice(2);
    if (array.length >= 3) {
       test(array);
    }
  }, timeInMilliseconds);
}

test(times);
```

```html
<p>ignore: <span id="ignore">-</span></p>
<p>test: <span id="test">-</span></p>
<p>display: <span id="display">-</span></p>
<p>Timer: <span id="timer"></span></p>
<p>Array: <span id="array"></span></p>
```